# Как узнать регион пользователя с помощью Geolocation HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Как узнать регион пользователя который зашёл на сайт?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что-то подобное можно использовать (**определение местоположения по координатам**):

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Страна: <span id="country"></span></p>
<p>Край(обл.): <span id="state"></span></p>
<p>Город: <span id="city"></span></p>
<p>Адрес: <span id="address"></span></p>
<p>Широта: <span id="latitude"></span></p>
<p>Долгота: <span id="longitude"></span></p>
```

**JS**

```
function displayError(error) {
  var errors = {
    1: 'Нет прав доступа',
    2: 'Местоположение невозможно определить',
    3: 'Таймаут соединения'
  };
  alert("Ошибка: " + errors[error.code]);
}

function displayPosition(position) {
  var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=ru';

  $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {

    $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
    $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
    $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);

    // в location.results[0] содержится больше всего информации об адресе
    for (var i = 0; i < location.results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
       switch(location.results[0].address_components[i].types[0]) {
         case 'locality':
           $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
           break;
         case 'administrative_area_level_1':
           $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
           break;
         case 'country':
           $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
           break;
       }
    }
  })
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    displayPosition,
    displayError, {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: timeoutVal,
      maximumAge: 0
    }
  );
} else {
  alert("Geolocation не поддерживается данным браузером");
}
```

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/tty37u7m/6/ (сюда в код не удалось импортировать этот пример, geolocation не реагирует)

Answer (score 2):

Пока существуют NAT и «серые» сети, про геолокацию можно забыть.

Дело в том, что из-за недостатка публичных («белых», всюду видимых) IPv4 адресов интернет-провайдер назначает их только некоторому количеству своих устройств, так называемым «NAT-шлюзам». Абонентам же, ровно как и внутренним маршрутизаторам, назначаются *локальные* («серые») адреса, невидимые за пределами шлюза; эти адреса повторяются от провайдера к провайдеру.

База же GeoIP, хранящая в себе географическую привязку подсетей, содержит в себе исключительно публичные подсети. Как результат, ***geolocation* определяет положение не пользователя, а провайдерского шлюза во «внешний» интернет**. С учётом того, что шлюзов как правило несколько, то каждое последующее подключение может быть «проброшено» через разные, вероятно географически распределённые, шлюзы.

Например: я живу в Тольятти, но *geolocation* определяет, что я живу то в Самаре, то в Москве.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можешь использовать готовый сервис https://location.ekolesnyk.com/ делаешь апи запрос получаешь ответ страна город координаты, пример

```
 $url = 'https://location.ekolesnyk.com/api/v1/country/?apiKey={apiKey}&ip=www.google.com';
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response, true); 

  if((isset($json['error']))){
  return $json['error']; //message error
  }

  return $json;
```