# Как определить район проживания человека?

Tags: html5, геолокация

Есть необходимость определять район проживания человека через точное определение местоположения на сайте. Возможно ли это? Если да, как именно это делается?

Comment: Вот так например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/544738/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-geolocation-html5/544759#544759