# Как вывести с карт по определении местоположения, город,страна?

Tags: google-maps

Есть готовый код он выводит координаты вашего местоположения но нужно еще что бы выводил город и страну!

```
var findMeButton = $('.find-me');

// Check if the browser has support for the Geolocation API
if (!navigator.geolocation) {

  findMeButton.addClass("disabled");
  $('.no-browser-support').addClass("visible");

} else {

  findMeButton.on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      // Get the coordinates of the current possition.
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;

      $('.latitude').text(lat.toFixed(3));
      $('.longitude').text(lng.toFixed(3));
      $('.coordinates').addClass('visible');

      // Create a new map and place a marker at the device location.
      var map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      });

      map.addMarker({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      });

    });

  });

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dannymarkov/ubrvm4ao/
нажмете на синюю кнопку!

Comment: На этот ответ посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544759/186083 Правда есть вероятность, что в разных координатах формат возвращаемых данных отличается в количестве возвращаемых элементов.

Comment: @Visman то что нужно!!!! спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

через гугл геокод можно получить:

```
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: lat + ',' + lng}, function (results, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK || !results[0]) {
            return;
        }
        var result = results[0];

        var city, region, country;

        for (var i = 0; i < result.address_components.length; i++) {
            if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "locality") {
                city = result.address_components[i];
            }
            if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "administrative_area_level_1") {
                region = result.address_components[i];
            }
            if (result.address_components[i].types[0] === "country") {
                country = result.address_components[i];
            }
        }

        alert(city.long_name + ", " + region.long_name + ", " + country.short_name)

        console.log(results);
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ubrvm4ao/298