# Определение города (параметра местоположения) на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, html, геолокация, geocode

Читал про geoloction api, но не нашел определение такого параметра как город. Читал пример на [недопонимаемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700487/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

но не понял какую роль играет свойство types. Не понятно какая размерность массива types (почему везде используется 0-й элемент этого массива)?